# Can I eager load Super Table fields in a Matrix block?

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-supertable, eager-loading

I have a Matrix with a Super Table in many of its blocks that I'm trying to eager load, but I can't figure out the syntax (or if its possible). The Super Table field's handle is `columnSize` and it contains two rows with dropdowns, `screenSize` and `columnSize`. My Matrix's handle is `contentBlocks`. The template code is below:

```
entry.contentBlocks.with(
    [
        'text:columnSize', // Super Table field
        'image:columnSize', // Super Table field
        ['image:image', {
            withTransforms: [{width: 1600, width: 1024, width: 768}]
        }], // Asset field
        ...
    ]
)
```

The syntax above works for every field I have except `columnSize`, which returns empty in the template when loaded using this method. Are there additional parameters needed for Super Table similar to image transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super Table doesn't yet support eager loading (its certainly high on the list). I'll keep you posted with progress, or feel free to submit an issue on the plugin page https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable/issues

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been added in the [0.4.7 release](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable/releases/tag/0.4.7)!

View the original issue [here](https://github.com/engram-design/SuperTable/issues/66).

Note: *I have not personally verified this functionality.*